# Why AutoRegression(AR) model in python is giving inaccurate negative prediction

Tags: time-series, python, predictive-models, autoregressive, statsmodels

I have time series data with 8 points. I used AR model from [statsmodels.tsa.ar_model](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html) library. I trained data using 8 points and predicted next 3 points. Though all values in the series are in increasing order, model predicts next values as negative. Why AutoRegression is giving that inaccurate result. Is it due to error in the code or insufficiency of the data(short series)?

Code:

```
rft=[1,7,8,20,59,133,223,247]
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
model=AR(rft)
model_fit = model.fit()
y_predicted=model_fit.predict(start=len(rft), end=len(rft)+3)
print(y_predicted)

Output:-
8      -25.113460
9    -1054.913428
10   -3537.131054
11   -8056.000283
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Sonali, have you noticed that this class is said to be "*Deprecated since v 0.11*"? Perhaps it is not maintained and this is a bug?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I didn't know about the class being deprecated. Is there any other class, using which I can use same functionality (Auto Regression) in Python3?

Comment: I'm not really an expert on this package. You'd have more luck raising an issue in its Github repo (https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in this example that lead to the strange-looking predictions.

1. Non-stationary (i.e. explosive) behavior
2. Short time series

The first problem is that the autoregression model assumes the data fluctuates around a stable mean value. This is not true of your data, which appears to increase something like exponentially.

The second problem is that you have a short time series, so the risk of overfitting is high.

The combination of these two things means that the model is severely overfitting your data. As usual, this leads to very poor out-of-sample performance.

In particular, the `fit` method selects the `order` of the autoregression. In this case, it is selecting an AR(6) model. Since you have only 8 datapoints, this is pretty good evidence of overfitting. Note that AR models typically perform better than this, even with short samples, but since your data is non-stationary, it is not an appropriate model for your data.

You would be better off with a simpler model, like an exponential smoothing model, or by modeling your data with e.g. a linear trend, e.g.:

```
mod = sm.tsa.SARIMAX([1,7,8,20,59,133,223,247], order=(1, 0, 0), trend='t')
res = mod.fit()
res.forecast(3)
```

which gives

```
array([290.63186209, 336.18574776, 383.12951135])
```

You could alternatively take differences to make your data stationary.

Comment: Is there any reason for using SARIMAX model over ARIMA?

Comment: The `sm.tsa.ARIMA` model is essentially maintenance-only right now. `sm.tsa.SARIMAX` and `sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA` (available in v0.11) are better models to use.